# Reset and submit form without empty values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have the following simple form:

```
<select name="category">
<option value="">Choose a Category</option>  
<option value="Social">Social</option>
<option value="Media">Media</option>
</select>
```

I use the following jquery to reset the form:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click', '.test', function(){  
  $('select[name*="category"]').val('');
  $('form').submit();
});
});
```

The problem is that the form is now submitted using an empty query string `/?category=` is there a way to make it submit the form without these empty query strings just to reset it?

Comment: Reload the page? Although I don't see the point of submitting a form with no values.

Comment: the point is that i want to enable the user to remove the filtering of categories to view all results again

Comment: use ajax to see results without submitting?

Answer (score 0):

I think submit is not required in your code just use following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.test', function () {
        $('select[name*="category"]').val('');
    });
});
```

Comment: i actually want to submit the form not just reset

Comment: first submit the form then rest

Comment: if the value for category is already set, submitting the form will submit it again

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest removing the control itself:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.test', function () {
        $('select[name*="category"]').remove();
        $('form').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: as you said i have other parameters that i need but removing the control doesn't solve the problem as it will submit also `?` at the end of the url...is there a way to prevent the question mark from getting submitted?

Comment: If so, use the second option. Removing the control will not send it as a parameter (because it will not exist in the submitted form)

Comment: now the question mark is still there so the url now is: `site.com/?`..is there a way to remove this `?` at the end of url?

Comment: If you need to redirect user to `site.com/` address, then you can simply do `window.location.href="/";`.
You do not need to manipulate the form in this kind of case - just redirect the user to the "bare" address.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('select[name*="category"]').val('');
  $(document).on('click', '.test', function () {
    $('select[name*="category"]').val('');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you truly want to reset the entire form, then use the basic JS `.reset()`.  In your code, you can do this by replacing your entire `click` function with:

```
$('form')[0].reset();
```

That will convert the selected JQuery object to the HTML node reference, so that you can use the JS `reset` function on it.  That will reset all of the fields in the form to their default values.

**NOTE:** Technically `$('form')[0]` is "the first object in the array of all forms on the page", so, if you have more than one form, you would need to be more specific, to make sure that you were resetting the intended form.

Comment: this will reset the form but not submit it...i need both and the submitted URL should not contain the empty query strings...can't just reload because I will lose other parameters in the url that I need

Comment: @MichaelSamuel - Let me see, if I understand . . . you want the dropdown to reset, and the "category" parameter to not be part of the URL string, but other form field values should still be in the URL?  Or are you saying that you want all form fields to be out of the URL and any other (non-form) parameters, to still be part of the URL?

Comment: the second option :) all form fields be reset (i mentioned here the select but have several form fields) and don't append them to the form when submitted...i somewhat was able to achieve it by removing the `name` attribute from the select but now `?` is getting submitted...is there a way to stop it from getting appended..i read it's in the structure of the `get` method and can't be removed

Comment: I guess what I'm having trouble understanding is, how are the other parameters (that you want to stay in the URL) getting appended?  IF they are not part of the form field, then they would be added by some other means and, when you reload the page, they should still be there.  If that is the case, than I'd suggest converting your foom from `GET` to `POST`, so that the parameters are not passed via the URL.

Comment: the parameters are also get variables....btw if i just reload and the url has already one of the form field appended, it will load again with those fields...so reloading isn't actually possible as the user may have already picked a category and it's loaded in the url

Comment: Can you update your question with "before and after" example URLs, showing what you're trying to do and where the various parameters come from?  I think we're having trouble trying to visualize exactly what the situation is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $('#frm').submit(function(form){
            $('#frm').find('[name="category"]').remove();
            form.submit();  
        });
```

this will remove the query parameter during form submit.

```
<html>
<head>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='file:///D:/bootstrap/js/jquery-ls.js'></script>
<body>
<form id='frm' method='get' action=''>
<select name="category" >
<option value="">Choose a Category</option>  
<option value="Social">Social</option>
<option value="Media">Media</option>
</select>

<input class='test' type='submit'  value='click' />
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('click','.test',function(){
        var data=$('#frm').serializeArray();
        //alert(data[0]['value']);
        console.log(data[0]);
        if(data[0]['value']){
        //  alert('t');
            $('frm').submit();
        }
        else{
        $('#frm')[0].reset();

        $('#frm').find('[name="category"]').remove();
    }
    });

});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: i'm now doing this but is there a way to also remove the `?` that gets appended?

Comment: @MichaelSamuel If we remove all form fields, then there will be no ? also. I tested locally and posted..

Comment: just tested locally this code alone and still the ? is getting appended :)